# Segmentation Fault Error; Absolute Value Table

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, absolute-value

I've been hammering myself on to this homework for a while now. And I can't seem to find what's wrong with it.

My question is why do I keep getting segmentation fault errors everytime I execute this program.

```
/* Description: A program that takes an input array argument with type double values and displays a table of those inputs and their absolute values.
*/

...

int main() /* Main Function */
{
    /* Variables */

    int size=5,n;
    double value[n];
    double table;

    /* Instructions and Input */

    for(n=0;n<size;n++){
            printf("\nPlease enter value #%d:\n",n);
            if(n=size-1){printf("\nPlease enter the last value.\n");}
            scanf("%lf",&value[n]);
    }

    /* Recalling the Function and Output */

    printf("\nValue\t|Value|\n"); /* Table Header */
    table=abs_table(value[n],size); /*Absolute Value Table */

    return 0;
}

double abs_table(double value, int size) /* Absolute Value Function */
{
    int i,j; /* Counter Variables */
    double v;

    for(j=1;j<=size;j++){ /* For the Number of rows */
            for(i=0;i<=size;i++){ /* For the number of columns */
                            v = abs(value); // For the absolute values */
                            printf("\n%g\t%g\n",value,v);
                    }
    printf("\n"); /* To make sure the rows display on their own line */
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: `double value[n];` `n` isn't initialised, thus undefined. It shouldn't even be allowed to compile, in any case, enable compiler warnings (`-Wall` for GCC).

Comment: Bugs, bugs everywhere.

Comment: Addressing the only question asked, because you're invoking undefined behavior due to an indeterminate value in a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several errors in your code:

Error1: in main() you declare `double value[n];` I believe what you want is `double value[size];`

Error2: in main() statement `if(n=size-1)` should be changed to `if(n==size-1)`

Error3: in main() you call function `table=abs_table(value[n],size);` it should be `table=abs_table(value,size);`

Error4: you define function `double abs_table(double value, int size){...}` it should be `double abs_table(double value[], int size){...}`

Error5: inside function `abs_table` I actually don't know what you are trying to display here. One spot is that variable `i` should run from 0 to size-1, another spot is that you should return something

Comment: He's not using `value` as an array inside `abs_table`, so it's technically not wrong to accept & pass a (normal) `double`.

Comment: You could be right, Kninnug. It is all up to him. According to the `for` loop inside the `abs_table` function I guess he actually wants to pass an array to it

Answer (score 1):

Many errors are in your program:

1. Array cannot be initialized with variable length `n`: `double value[n];`.
2. One additional `=` is missing in `if(n=size-1)`.
3. Even if you initialized array correctly with length `n` (point 1) then `scanf("%lf",&value[n]);` will write to a memory location beyond the length of the `value` array.
4. `abs` is coded for integer but not double: `v = abs(value);`.
5. ...possibly some more errors but the list is already quite long.

Comment: I don't think he wants to print the address of `n`, so an ampersand isn't necessary.

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` you declare `int n` without initialising it and subsequently `double value[n]`. Therefore `n` has an undefined value and thus `value` is of undefined size. I think you meant to declare `double value[size]`, which you did initialize.

Also, `abs_table` is supposed to return a `double` but you're returning void.